# How can we see hats I earned?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

I have participated in the Winter Bash and can see that many users have profile icons with hats on it. I think I earned one hat, but can't see it on my profile. Am I missing something?

Comment: shows on your profile itself...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your hats count on your profile, click it, then click on one of the hats.

[image]

Comment: I click on my hats and it says "Your Hats loading..." and nothing more.  It must be trying to run something that is blocked from work.  At least I know now why I can see others' hats but not mine.

Answer (score 11):

When you earned a hat, you'll be notified by the `Winter Bash` notifier in the title bar:

[image: hat notifier]

And you'll find a hat count in your profile:

[image: hat count]

To wear a hat, click on the count and pick a hat to wear:

[image: hat selection]

Alternatively, you can click on your profile picture (on your profile page) to switch hats. If you click the circled hat again, you'll remove it.

Comment: Correct. I can see 1 there. But nothing on the pic ? How to display it there ?

Comment: @AYK: Click on the count, then choose a hat to wear. You need to don the hat to show it!

Answer (score 6):

Go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529189/ayk) and see below profile views (for other's profile) or helpful flags (for your own profile).

> [image]

Another option:

Go to [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) and login there. You can see there active whichever is earned by you.

Comment: Correct. I can see 1 there. But nothing on the pic ? How to display it there ?

Comment: [I can see in your profile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/puF0Q.png)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted to wear it :)

Comment: @AYK - To wear it [click on any of those hats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Alf.png)

Comment: @AYK - You have earned another hat for asking this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated UI (as of 2015): to access your hats click on the hat graphic on the Activity tab of your profile:

[image: hat grapheme in context]

This lets you choose any hat you've earned on any site:

[image: hat rack]