# Why don't hats appear in our profile popup?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2012, user-card

[Winterbash](http://winterba.sh/) hats appear our profile when we [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93502/page-without-answers-in-stack-overflow), when we [answered a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting/85595#85595), in our [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158761/soner-gonul), but not our profile popup. Why? Is there any integration problem for this? If there isn't, please put this feature to the profile popup.

[image]

Comment: why hats are not appear in char ?

Comment: @NullPointer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159194/187824

Comment: You lucky bastard. My hat doesn't appear at all!

Comment: @MrLister : Refer my question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159251/how-can-we-see-hats-earned-by-ourselves), for details on how to "wear" your hat.

Comment: Ah... I missed that step; I thought _"I like hats"_ was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been implemented in Winterbash 2013

[image]

Rejoice!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this just because: there's no good way to implement this right now without site performance taking a big hit.

That said, for myself, I rarely use that usercard popup (for one, despite moderator powers, I haven't earned it on many sites at all) so having hats there would be rather on the useless side for me. For another, it felt much more organic to change hats using the Winter Bash dropdown and clicking through my user profile. All other changes regarding my avatar happen by editing the email in my profile -- why not what hat I have equipped?

Your idea isn't bad -- we'll consider it for next year. :)

Comment: I think the request was not about editing hats via the profile popup, but rather show the hat on that profile pic - or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Spontifixus Oh. If that's the case: performance is likely still the reason. It's also an Ajax popup right? It might have just been too expensive for the value -- that is, too much dev time for too few uses.

Comment: Thanks for consider this in Winterbash 2013 `:)`