# What do I need to do to in order to wear my hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we see hats earned by ourselves?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159251/how-can-we-see-hats-earned-by-ourselves)

I've got a winter bash hat, but it does not show up.
I pressed "I love hats". What more do I need to do?

Hmmm... Meta StackOverflow does not seem to think that short questions merits attention, so let me go on and on about how sad I am to be seen in public without my hat, until the stupid algorithm let this pass ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your profile, click the number next to the `hats` section (alternatively, your profile picture).

[image: hats link]

A list of hats you can use will show up.

[image: hats you have]

Click on the hat you wish to wear.

Comment: a click on the profile picture will work too

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - Didn't realize that. Thanks.